# Caching expensive SQL query in memory or in the database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, caching, entity-framework-4, asp.net-caching, database-caching

Let me start by describing the scenario. I have an MVC 3 application with SQL Server 2008. In one of the pages we display a list of Products that is returned from the database and is UNIQUE per logged in user.
The SQL query (actually a VIEW) used to return the list of products is VERY expensive.

- It is based on very complex business requirements which cannot be changed at this stage.
- The database schema cannot be changed or redesigned as it is used by other applications.
- There are 50k products and 5k users (each user may have access to 1 up to 50k products).

In order to display the Products page for the logged in user we use:

```
SELECT TOP X * FROM [VIEW] WHERE UserID = @UserId -- where 'X' is the size of the page
```

The query above returns a maximum of 50 rows (maximum page size). The WHERE clause restricts the number of rows to a maximum of 50k (products that the user has access to).
The page is taking about 5 to 7 seconds to load and that is exactly the time the SQL query above takes to run in SQL.
**Problem**:

The user goes to the Products page and very likely uses paging, re-sorts the results, goes to the details page, etc and then goes back to the list. And every time it takes 5-7s to display the results.

That is unacceptable, but at the same time the business team has accepted that the first time the Products page is loaded it can take 5-7s. Therefore, we thought about **CACHING**.

We now have two options to choose from, the most "obvious" one, at least to me, is using .Net Caching (in memory / in proc). (Please note that Distributed Cache is not allowed at the moment for technical constraints with our provider / hosting partner).

But I'm not very comfortable with this. We could end up with lots of products in memory (when there are 50 or 100 users logged in simultaneously) which could cause other issues on the server, like .Net constantly removing cache items to free up space while our code inserts new items.

The **SECOND** option:

The main problem here is that it is very EXPENSIVE to generate the User x Product x Access view, so we thought we could create a flat table (or in other words a CACHE of all products x users in the database). This table would be exactly the result of the view.
However the results can change at any time if new products are added, user permissions are changed, etc. So we would need to constantly refresh the table (which could take a few seconds) and this started to get a little bit complex.

Similarly, we though we could implement some sort of Cache Provider and, upon request from a user, we would run the original SQL query and select the products from the view (5-7s, acceptable only once) and save that result in a flat table called ProductUserAccessCache in SQL. Next request, we would get the values from this cached-table (as we could easily identify the results were cached for that particular user) with a fast query without calculations in SQL.
Any time a product was added or a permission changed, we would truncate the cached-table and upon a new request the table would be repopulated for the requested user.
It doesn't seem too complex to me, but what we are doing here basically is creating a NEW cache "provider".

- Does any one have any experience with this kind of issue?
- Would it be better to use .Net Caching (in proc)?
- Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using an ORM?

Answer (score 1):

We were facing a similar issue some time ago, and we were thinking of using EF caching in order to avoid the delay on retrieving the information. Our problem was a 1 - 2 secs. delay. [Here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers) is some info that might help on how to cache a table extending EF. One of the drawbacks of caching is how fresh you need the information to be, so you set your cache expiration accordingly. Depending on that expiration, users might need to wait to get the fresh info more than they would like to, but if your users can accept that they migth be seing outdated info in order to avoid the delay, then the tradeoff would worth it.

In our scenario, we decided to better have the fresh info than quick, but as I said before, our waiting period wasn't that long.

Hope it helps

Comment: I wasn't aware of this one. It seems very powerful and I will investigate it. From a quick look though I think it won't cover all my needs, but it is worth trying.tx